# Applescript to change Wacom Driver settings

Tags: applescript, system-settings

Can an Applescript change the primary monitor option within the Wacom Driver, and do it near instantly?

Comment: If it can be done via a shell script, yes, otherwise probably, depends... Can you supply the way this driver option is done normally?

Comment: I still don't understand what a shell-script is exactly. But it's my own fault, I can't sit thru tutorials so suffer thru learing via trial and error after error.

Comment: The driver option is the monitor calibration setting, controling which display the tablet is mapped to. In this case it's a cintiq, so it is naturally the primary display. But when it is switched to the other display, the cursor jumps to that that display,an action that is almost identical to the Display Toggle function. Which is what I've been trying to replicate as a keyboard shortcut since getting my cintiq. It's become an obsession.

Comment: a shell script is a way to encapsulate one or several lines of commands (probably not the best definition, but summing up, it is a way to send simple (and complex) commands to your system). Your request may be simpler to accomplish with some app. that allows you to add shortcuts to common actions. You could try Buttler, (http://manytricks.com/butler/ version 4.1.6 is free), or even at the system prefs you have a way to add shortcuts, at the keyboard & mouse prefs.

Comment: Btw, if you're wondering: I want to do this so that when painting in Photoshop my pen buttons can be used for brush sizing. Display Toggle works fine as one of these buttons everywhere else, but when I paint I tend to hit this button accidentally, usually in mid stroke, causing much swearing and pen-throwing. Stupid I know...But there are a few others that feel my pain, and no one has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Wacom driver allows you to set things up for individual applications. Have a specific setup for Photoshop (which excludes the display toggle setting) and then another one for all other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions Joe. Tried Butler among others, and it seems to come down to needing a script, and the only type of script (or workflow, action etc) is one that will just mimic the actions of opening the pane, the driver within, and then the pulldown change. All too glitchy and long for the immediacy I require. If it's not as fast the Display Toggle action then it's no use. Maybe a shellscript can do these as a system event directly?

I started this quest first by trying to hack/remap/script the Display Toggle feature as a keyboard shortcut, but after trying every 3rd party app or hack there is, I just don't think it can be done. I can't even capture the button action because of the HID nature of the device.

Answer (score 0):

There is apple script in this page [How to switch tablet input between multiple monitors on a Mac](http://jjhale.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-switch-tablet-input-between-multiple-monitors-on-a-mac/). I tried it but I do not get it to work on my setup. I guess it's outdated, maybe somebody can update it.